# Why is (javax.servlet.)SingleThreadModel deprecated?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

Why is [`javax.servlet.SingleThreadModel`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/SingleThreadModel.html) deprecated?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/SingleThreadModel.html) says why. `SingleThreadModel` was designed to be an easy solution to low-load concurrency, but it didn't even manage that:

> Note that SingleThreadModel does not
>   solve all thread safety issues. For
>   example, session attributes and static
>   variables can still be accessed by
>   multiple requests on multiple threads
>   at the same time, even when
>   SingleThreadModel servlets are used.
>   It is recommended that a developer
>   take other means to resolve those
>   issues instead of implementing this
>   interface, such as avoiding the usage
>   of an instance variable or
>   synchronizing the block of the code
>   accessing those resources.

If it can't achieve what it was designed for, it should not be used.

Comment: How can static variables and session attributes be accessed by multiple requests when 1 request = 1 thread. And STM uses only **one** thread at a time. I know I am not a senior, but I disagree with this. Could you correct me?

Comment: Note: `SingleThreadModel` has been deprecated since Servlet 2.4 and is being removed in Servlet 6.0.

Answer (score 11):

It's basically a poor way of handling concurrency. Take the state out of your servlet instead, so that the same servlet can be used by multiple threads concurrently. Keeping state in a "pool" of servlet instances, each of which can have state left over from the previous request etc is pretty horrible.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes SingleThreadModel interface is deprecated. Do not use it.** In fact you don't need it, instead use local variables instead of object fields since "each thread gets its own copy of local variables in Java. By simply removing the object field and replacing it with a local variable, this particular threading problem is resolved." [Reference](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/jxslt/ch06_05.htm)

Answer (score 2):

From Java Servlet Spec:

> The use of the SingleThreadModel interface guarantees that only one
>   thread at a time will execute in a given servlet instance’s service
>   method. It is important to note that this guarantee only applies to
>   each servlet instance, since the container may choose to pool such
>   objects. Objects that are accessible to more than one servlet instance
>   at a time, such as instances of HttpSession, may be available at any
>   particular time to multiple servlets, including those that implement
>   SingleThreadModel.
>   
>       It is recommended that a developer take other means to resolve those issues instead of implementing this interface, such as avoiding
>   the usage of an instance variable or synchronizing the block of the
>   code accessing those resources. The SingleThreadModel Interface is
>   deprecated in this version of the specification.

Answer (score 0):

If a servlet implements `SingleThreadModel` interface, servlet container can create one or multiple instance of the servlet depend on the request load. Each instance will use only their `service()` method. It solves thread safety issues but not  all of them. Such as static class variables, session attributes are still not thread safe.

Instead of using this interface developer encouraged to use synchronizing the block of the code accessing those resources.